# Finding Microsoft document about 'globe' contact in Outlook Address Book

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, contacts, addressbook

Sorry first because this problem does not relate to programing language. But I think developers is used to working with it.

In my Outlook Address Book, I see some contacts that have a globe icon next to it, but I dont know exactly what they mean.

I also searched on GG, and some of pepole said that they were custom recipients, i.e., their mailboxes were on some other system outside the Exchange organization...

I am not clear about that. So, I need to find Microsoft documents about this problem. But, I dont receive any right results.

If you got the similar issues, please give me an advice! I need MS document about "globe" contact to answer my questions: Does they exist on AD or Exchange? How to find them?...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They're contact objects in AD. Exchange doesn't store any data you see in the GAL.